Ubuntu 24.04 - LVM - RAID5 - Different Disk Sizes - Stat & Report
I want to setup a RAID5 using LVM, with different disk sizes:
2 x 2TB
3 x 1TB
My first question is, what is the best/secure setup to do with my actual config:

Partitionning the 2TB into 1TB/partition

7 PV of 1TB each into a single VG
1 LV using RAID5 : lvcreate --stripes 6 --type raid5 --size 100%VG --name lv-name vg-name
=> result is a size of 6TB


Regrouping the 1TB into 2TB (leaving 1 disk behind), but I do not know how this could be done... and if it is even possible???

Maybe... merging 1 VG of 4TB (2 x 2TB : vg-name) and 1 VG of 2TB (2 x 1TB : new-vg) : vgmerge -v vg-name new-vg
Then 1 LV RAID5 : lvcreate --stripes 2 --type raid5 --size 100%VG --name lv-name vg-name
=> result should be a size of 5TB



Actually for testing I've setup the first 1 solution with 7 PV, and the first sync is taking forever it's been almost 24Hrs and it is only at 39.45%.
So I'm wondering why, and I want to have some output/stats/report about my config to maybe understand it a bit more.
So here comes my second question, How to have some info about the stats (speed I/O, Synchronasiton status, Health etc...)?
I Know about:

lvs -a -o name,copy_percent,health_status,devices vg-name
Some usefull link like Red Hat Doc about LVM reports
lvm fullreport (but the output is unreadable... I mean it is not displayed well at all), Red Hat Doc is talking about it but no example, nor tips to customize a bit the output...

Thanks for your time.

If you are going to do this using LVM, you don't need to make all PVs of the same size. In LVM RAID, the erasure coding is made for each logical volume separately, not for physical volumes.
In particular, don't partition 2 TB drives into 1 TB. Your "solution" with 7 PVs is even wrong, because it's not redundant at all: loss of any of 2 TB drives will cause the loss of the array. Also each 2 TB drive is written to twice for each stripe, in disjoint areas — which means, extra seeking. Yes, that must horribly hurt the performance!
Choose two or three drives to make a small ESP or boot partitions on them and partition everything else into a large partition spanning the rest of the space. And then, when allocating your logical volumes, you may divide the space however you want: you may arrange some LVs to behave like RAID1, some like RAID6, some without redundancy at all, all over the same single VG of 7 TB raw space. The most space you can use reliably this way might be 3 TB of RAID6 over 5 drives + 1 TB of RAID1 over two drives = 4 TB.
With only RAID1 you may end end up with having up to 3.5 TB of space, with generally much better performance than RAID6 — so I'd choose this path in your case; that 500 GB of difference is not worth struggling with RAID6.
Also, may I remind you against using RAID5 on large hard disks.

First thank you for your time and your reminder ;) - LOL never again RAID5 !!
For my so called "solution" I was thinking the same (about losing one 2TB drive) but not as far as you say when you talked about performances... Hopefully I was just playing with LVM and RAID.
Lastly the OS is installed on a separate drive and not included in my future RAID array, so I don't think I need any boot or ESP partition, right? And If I understand you correctly I should go for RAID1 (maybe RAID1+0?)?
Is LVM the right choice for RAID1? If not, I will not be able to use different disk size, isn't it?

Yes, if you boot from something else, you don't need to have ESP. In fact, you don't need to partition these disks at all... I don't know what your demands really are, it all depends on what you are going to do with this. LVM RAID is pretty stable and flexible however, there is a distinctive trend to shift the focus into RAID-incorporating filesystems. Try ZFS and BTRFS, and it's worth playing with bcachefs, which was included into vanilla kernel in the beginning of January 2024 and it looks very promising. With bcachefs, you will have 3.5 TB of mirrored flesystem space out of these disks.

Ok, I need to think everything over again. I'll have a look and try to find the best solution that suits my needs. Thanks for your advice.

After reading a bit (surely not enough), I wanna try bcachefs, but I'm lost when you say that I can achieve 3.5TB RAID1 with it... As far as I can see, I'll have to make a first array with the 2x2TB (RAID1 = 2TB), but I'm confused of how I'm supposed to use the last 3x1TB. How should it be done? 2 array of RAID0 with 1 drive + 1/2 drive, then a RAID1 array with this? Or directly a RAID1 array after partitioning the third drive in half?

It doesn't stripe by devices. It stripes each file and tries to distribute blocks so to fill all the devices up to the same percentage. An allocator finds the most free device and writes there, and that means, with many files, all five disks will be filled equally; if you set replicas to 2, it will store each block twice and on different devices, efficiently mirroring everything. (There are other considerations; read the bcachefs manual for details. It would attempt to use the least busy devices first for instance, that is to reduce the I/O latency.)

I'm stuck in the material world... Ok not about devices. so simple enough my command should look this: bcachefs format /dev/sdX /dev/sdY /dev... --replicas=n but as I'm new to this world of soft RAID, what number replicas should be, considering my configuration of 2x2TB + 3x1TB for a RAID1? And what number for a RAID10?

Wouldn't you read the manual please?

Sorry for my previous comment, and after reading I got it. From "2.2.1 Replication", I it should be --replicas=2. I'm learning here, and trying to get my head over these things...
